# VB6 - parameters, TYPE OF, Boolean

Tags: function, vb6, boolean, procedure

I have a function called `CHECK_DATE` - that allows for a parameter. The `CHECK_DATE` function takes the parameter as string and verifies that it's a valid date. What I'm trying to do, on Xing out the form, I ask the user if they want to save the changes - and if they click yes- then I save their changes. What I'm doing is going by the PREFIX and if its txt then I check why type of txt it is, whether textbox of maskedTextbox. If it's masked and date then send it to `CHECK_DATE(date)`

```
Dim CTL as Boolean
If TypeOf CTL Is TextBox Then
         'do nothing
ElseIf TypeOf CTL Is MaskEdBox Then
    if check_Date(ctl???) = true then<-- not sure what to put here.
         msgbox "goodDate"
    Else
         msgbox "Bad date"
    End

Public Function CHECK_DATE(CTL as string) as Boolean
    'I do my checking here
End Function
```

Basically I get stuck because I have no idea how to pass the value to the function. On the `CHECK_Date` end the parameter is string. But I haven't a clue how to pass it on. When I hoover over typeof CTL it shows me a date but I don't know hwo to pass it as parameter to the function?

Comment: TypeOf Ctl is always going to be Boolean - you just said so the line above.  Otherwise, pass TextBox.Text to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function must be :

```
Public Function CHECK_DATE(clt As Control) As Boolean
'I do my checking here
```

End Function

And you can call it by passing the name of your control in parameter without ".text" like :

```
CHECK_DATE (Text1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check_Date(ctl.text) passes the value and let me check it